# Can't get song duration in onCreate , but can get it on button pressed

Tags: android, media-player, android-context

I have a custom media service and an audio player class which communicates with it but is not bound to the service.

When I create an object of MyService and write the code :-
`myService.player.getDuration()`  in `onCreate` I get the null pointer exception on this line.

But if I write this code on click of some button listener on the same screen then I get the exact duration.

I have tried every possible syntax to solve this but m still not able to resolve the problem.

** The code of my service is :-**

```
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static MediaPlayer player;
    String song_uri,url;
    Bundle b;
    private IBinder myBinder;
    private boolean isplaying;
    public static final String Song_uri="song_uri";
    public static final String EXTRA_SHUFFLE="EXTRA_SHUFFLE";

        @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public class MyBinder extends Binder{
        MyService getService()
        {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate "+song_uri);
            }   


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DataManager.getInstance().setWantsToPlaySong(false);
        DataManager.getInstance().setCurrentPosition(0);
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    //player.release();
    }

public void onPause()
{

player.pause();
}

public double duration()
{
return player.getDuration();    
}

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        DataManager.getInstance().setWantsToPlaySong(true);
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    song_uri=b.getString("song_uri");
    Uri path=Uri.parse(song_uri);


    player = MediaPlayer.create(this,path );
    player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started"+" Duration = "+(player.getDuration()/1000)/60, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart"+song_uri);
        player.start();
    }
```

The code of Audio Player is :-

```
 uri = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("song_uri");
        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        buttonPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);
        tracks = dbManager.getAllSongs(AudioPlayer2.this);

        buttonForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonforward);
        buttonBackward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonbackward);
        //=========================================================================================
        sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
          //myservice=new MyService();

        Uri path = Uri.parse(uri);
        current_song=this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("current_song");
        albumArtUri = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("album_art");
        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
         album_id = Long.parseLong(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("album_id"));
        int id = Integer.parseInt(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("album_id"));

        albumImageUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
        ivAlbumArt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.album_art);

        songName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("song_name");
        albumName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("album_name");

        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvAlbum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_album);
        if (songName != null) {
            tvName.setText(songName);
        }

        if (albumName != null) {
            tvAlbum.setText(albumName);
        }

    //  buttonStart.performClick();

        if (DataManager.getInstance().getOnPausedSong()=="y"){
            //Toast.makeText(AudioPlayer2.this, "stage 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(DataManager.getInstance().getPausedSongName()==songName){
                //Toast.makeText(AudioPlayer2.this, "stage 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            buttonStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        }
        FetchImage fetchImage = new FetchImage();
        fetchImage.execute();

          /*if(DataManager.getInstance().getSong_uri()!=null)
          {
              stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          }*/
    //  if(myService.player.isPlaying())
        //{
         stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("song_uri",uri );
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startService(intent);
            myService.player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    buttonStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            buttonStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //  Toast.makeText(this, "Duration: "+myService.player.getDuration(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         /*//}//DataManager.getInstance().setSong_uri(uri); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("song_uri",uri );
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startService(intent);
        buttonStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DataManager.getInstance().setSong_uri(uri);
        DataManager.getInstance().setOnPausedSong("y");
        DataManager.getInstance().setPausedSongName(songName);
        */  //buttonStart.setPressed(true);

        //=======================================================================================
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonForward.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonBackward.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
      // buttonPause.performClick();
/*        new Thread(myThread).start();

*/    }

      // Thread for seekbar


        // song starts playing

      public void onClick(View src) {
        switch (src.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonStart:
            if(DataManager.getInstance().getSongPause()=="y"){
                myService.player.start();
                DataManager.getInstance().setSongPause("n");
                buttonStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //  DataManager.getInstance().setWantsToPlaySong(true);
                //DataManager.getInstance().setOnPausedSong("n");
                //DataManager.getInstance().setOnPausedSong("y");
            }else{
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
            DataManager.getInstance().setSong_uri(uri); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("song_uri",uri );
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startService(intent);
            buttonStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DataManager.getInstance().setOnPausedSong("y");
            DataManager.getInstance().setPausedSongName(songName);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonStop:
          Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
          stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          buttonStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     break;
        case R.id.buttonforward:
             stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
             current_song++;
            FetchAllMusic fetchAllMusic = new FetchAllMusic();
            fetchAllMusic.execute();
            //new Thread(myThread).start();


                break;
        case R.id.buttonbackward:
              Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping service");
              stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
              if(current_song>0){   
              current_song--;
               }
                FetchAllMusic fetchAllMusic2 = new FetchAllMusic();
                fetchAllMusic2.execute();

              break;
        case R.id.buttonPause:
              buttonStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            /* MyService myservice=new MyService();
             myservice.onPause();*/
                myService.player.pause();
                DataManager.getInstance().setSongPause("y");
                DataManager.getInstance().setWantsToPlaySong(false);
                DataManager.getInstance().setOnPausedSong("n");
                DataManager.getInstance().setPausedSongName(songName);
                //duration=myService.player.getDuration();

            //   Toast.makeText(this, ""+duration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
      }
        public void onBackPressed() {
            try {
                    //addvideo.removeView(DBManager.getInstance().getVideo());
                DataManager.getInstance().setSong_uri(uri);
            DataManager.getInstance().setAlbum_id(""+album_id);
            DataManager.getInstance().setAlbumName(albumName);
            DataManager.getInstance().setSongName(songName);
            DataManager.getInstance().setAlbumArtUri(albumArtUri);
            DataManager.getInstance().setCurrent_song(current_song);
            DataManager.getInstance().setWantsToPlaySong(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

          private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){

              @Override
              public void run() {
                      Log.d(TAG, "Thread Starts");
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              while (myProgress<100){
              try{
                      Log.d(TAG, "Thread Starts");
                      myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
              Thread.sleep(3000);
              }
              catch(Throwable t){
              }
              }
              }

              Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              myProgress++;
              seekbar.setProgress(myProgress);
              }
              };
              };
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a syntax problem; it's a variable initialization problem. Either `myService` or `myService.player` is `null` when that line executes in `onCreate()`. Check your code for where you are initializing these and make sure that you don't reference them before they are set.

Comment: where should i initialize in code? i have done possibly everything i have even initialized it in my baseScreen which every activity in my application extends to. myService.player can not be null because song is playing and myService can not be null since it is the variable initialized in baseScreen class

Comment: now i wrote this peice of code   myService = new MyService();
     Toast.makeText(AudioPlayer2.this, ""+myService.player.getDuration(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  and even this is giving me the nullPointer Exception...    Please Help

Comment: Does the `MyService()` constructor assign a value to `player`? If nott, that's your problem. (If, as you say, the code works in an onClick listener, I suspect that `player` gets assigned somewhat later in your code's execution.)